# Android database search in a column

Tags: android

I want to search into my sql database and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong , this is my code :

```
public Cursor getSomeData(String text){



    return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME},
            PERSON_TABLE_COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[] {"%" + text + "%"},
            null, null, null);
}
```

And here is my edittext which is doing the search

```
searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String text = searchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this , databaseHelper.getSomeData(text));
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        }
```

I want if I write a letter to show every words frm my database which contains that letter or is starting with it ! Thank you for your time !

Comment: It seems you want to use an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: Is it crashing or is it just doing nothing? Also, are you opening and closing the database between operations?

Comment: also you might want to change your `"%" + text + "%"` to `"'%" + text + "%'"`

Comment: @Ayoub I am , but I want to know if I'm returning right the query from my database  , my app is doing nothing , I mean if I 'll write something in my edittext will not display my upgradated listview , will show the listview with my all data !